# How to rearrange a 4 digit number contained in a single cell in large to small format

Tags: google-sheets

I have been using excel to convert a 4 digit number in a cell and rearrange the digits in large to small manner using a formula as in the pic.

For example 2439 is in cell E5, when applied this formula, LARGE(--MID(E5,{1,2,3,4},1),@{1,2,3,4})&LARGE(--MID(E5,{1,2,3,4},1),@{2,3,4})&LARGE(--MID(E5,{1,2,3,4},1),@{3,4})&LARGE(--MID(E5,{1,2,3,4},1),@{4}), returns 9432. As you can see 9,4,3,2 is arranged large to small.

***How can I do the same in Google Sheets?*** please advise. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a single array formula that will process all valid rows at once. For instance, given data that starts in E5 as shown (with a header in in E4), place the following in F4:

`=ArrayFormula({"Mod"; IF(E5:E="",,REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE(E5:E&"","[^"&SEQUENCE(1,10,9,-1)&"]","")),,10)),"\s",""))})`

This will generate the header "Mod" in F4 (which you can change to something else within the formula if you like).

Each row thereafter will be left blank if the corresponding row in E5:E is also blank *or* if the value in E5:E is not a number.

If a value in E5:E is a combination of digits and non-digits, non-digits will be ignored (e.g., `12cat3` will result in `321`).

Otherwise, a ten-column array is formed for each row, replacing any digits that are *not* 9, 8, 7, etc. with null. This will get the digits in descending order, but separated into columns.

The `TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE( ),,10))` will "squash" those 10 columns back into one.

Finally, the outer `REGEXREPLACE` will remove any spaces (where those 10 columns didn't have numbers and where existing numbers would have been originally joined).

Always be sure, when using such array formulas, that you understand that the array formula "owns" the range you've assigned it to process (in this case, F4:F). So make sure that range is clear of data or formulas before placing the array formula in F4. Then do not attempt to enter data manually in that range, or you will "break" the array: all data will disappear except what you manually entered, and cell F4 will show an error.

Comment: very nice, good, I gave an upvote ... just one very small note: the result of your formula is text, so I preferred to transform it into a number with value ()

Comment: Thanks. It was not mentioned in the original post whether these were true numbers or serials (i.e., strings). I assumed the latter, since there were no commas present and because of the nature of the task. Myself, if I want to convert a string back to a number, I tend to use `1*`, e.g., `=ArrayFormula({"Mod"; IF(E5:E="",,1*REGEXREPLACE(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE(E5:E&"","[^"&SEQUENCE(1,10,9,-1)&"]","")),,10)),"\s",""))})`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: large to small]

This is the draggable formula I used:

```
=IF(E5="",,VALUE(JOIN("",SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE("" & E5, "(\d)", "$1,"), ",")),1,0))))
```

**Explanation**

`REGEXREPLACE("" & E5, "(\d)", "$1,")` inserts a comma between each digit

`SPLIT()` puts each digit in a different cell

`TRANSPOSE()` puts the digits in a single column

`SORT()` sorts the digits from highest to lowest

`JOIN()` brings digits in a single cell

`VALUE()` transforms the resulting text into a number

**note** on the reason for the space inserted in the `"" & E5` part of `regexreplace()` : it was necessary to transform the initial number into text, the only acceptable element for the aforementioned function

Comment: Wow. it works perfectly. Thank you so much. It would have taken me years to figure this out on my own. You are amazing. Thank you.